# online Control Property editor like control property editor in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I can imagine it will require heavy javascript and ajax to build such editor but couldn't find any sample on internet.

Can someone please provide some sample, reference or anything could help?

thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the demo on [dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/property.html](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/property.html)

[image]

Comment: link updated here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/property.html. If this link also broken in future, please goto the example portal: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/ and you can find all kinds of grids there.